# what does it mean when uid equals to zero for Android system

Tags: android, android-service, uid, android-binder

In the NotificationManagerService.java from Android 5.0 framework source code.
I don't understand when the uid will be zero.

```
private static boolean isUidSystem(int uid) {
    final int appid = UserHandle.getAppId(uid);
    return (appid == Process.SYSTEM_UID || appid == Process.PHONE_UID || uid == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android's `Process` class contains the following definitions (among others):

```
/**
 * Defines the root UID.
 */
public static final int ROOT_UID = 0;

/**
 * Defines the UID/GID under which system code runs.
 */
public static final int SYSTEM_UID = 1000;

/**
 * Defines the UID/GID under which the telephony code runs.
 */
public static final int PHONE_UID = 1001;
```

These framework values correspond to kernel `uid`s for the `root`, `system`, and `radio` users. In Android, many system processes run as one of these three `uid`s.

NotificationManagerService uses `isUidSystem()` to check if the calling process is owned by one of these users and if so, set the boolean `isSystemNotification` (it also ends up true if the package name begins with `android.*`).

Note that `isSystemUid` doesn't directly compare the calling `uid` with the above values, but first runs it through `UserHandle.getAppId()`, which takes the kernel value and mods it with `UserHandle.PER_USER_RANGE`, normally defined as 100000 (i.e., `uid % PER_USER_RANGE`). This ends up being the last five digits of the kernel `uid`, where the first two correspond to the `userId` on multi-user devices.

So the `uid` and `appId` will be 0 for processes and apps that are running as the root user, and `isSystemUid()` will return `true` in this case. It will also return true whenever the uid is from a caller running as the `system` or `radio` user.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured, the code means only return true for system uid, phone uid, and root uid(which equals to 0)